# S bar 4 head light fixture 1 head not working

Tags: electrical

I have a 4 head S bar light fixture that uses 50W halogen bulbs. One of the heads is not working. I have ohmed the wiringing to the head and the wires are fine. I have tried multiple bulbs that work in another head and they will not light when in this head. The sockets are the two post insert and twist to lock. Any suggestion on what it might be will be appreciated.

Comment: just because the meter probe will make contact in the socket does not mean that a light bulb also makes contact

Comment: Yes, try it with a burnt out bulb, you should have plenty of those, break the glass off and put the meter on the electrodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did try to bend the contacts in the socket out some but the bulb still isn't lighting. I will work on it some more to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

As spoken above, I can only assume that the individual socket is bad.  I would look for a replacement.